# PHP - trying to concat to LI's with echo and php and missing something

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation

Trying to concat these PHP expressions into LI's but it's getting rendered as the php first and then the LI's...

```
function getVolArchives() {
    query_posts('category_name=volunteerspotlights&showposts=5');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();          
        echo '<li>' . the_title() . '</li><li>' . the_date('F') . '</li>';
    endwhile;
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't work like I thought it should...can I get some help?

What happens is that the TITLE and DATE show up and THEN two blank LI's... but the answer was already given to me below.  I was using the wrong Wordpress functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `get_the_title()` and `get_the_date()` instead. In Wordpress, the `get_*()` versions of functions RETURN their data. Otherwise WP defaults to outputting the data instead.

Comment: Aw.... thank you.  So the syntax is correct IF your function returns a value... right?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it'd be fine - as far as anything WP-related could be considered "fine".